# How can a sum be limited up and down by an Integral?

Tags: integration, summation

> I have this sum $\sum_{n=1}^{k^2-1} \sqrt {n}$.
> I saw that this can be written as
> $$
> \int_0^{k^2-1} \sqrt {x} \,dx \leq \sum_{n=1}^{k^2-1}  {\sqrt {n}} \leq \int_1^{k^2}  \sqrt {x} \,dx
> $$

Can someone explain why is this true?

Comment: Think of writing a Riemann integral as a sum of rectangles of length $1$.

Answer (score 2):

For $n\le x \le n+1$, $\sqrt{n}\le \sqrt{x} \le \sqrt{n+1}$, so $\sqrt{n}\le \int_n^{n+1} \sqrt{x}dx$, while $\int_{n-1}^n \sqrt{x}dx\le \sqrt{n}$.  Take the sums over $n$ to get the desired result.

Comment: First of all , i did not understand why it this true $n \leq x \leq n+1$ .And then , isn't this supposed to be an integral in both sides? basically i dont understand this thing: $\sqrt(n) \leq  int_{n}^{n+1} \sqrt{x} \,dx $?Also isnt this supposed to be : $\int_{n-1}^{n} \sqrt{x} \,dx \ \leq \sqrt{n+1}$

Comment: The first statement is simply an assertion that when $x$ is between $n$ and $n+1$, $\sqrt{x}$ has the given limits.  Next $\int_{n-1}^n ndx=n$.  Finally For $n\le x$, we have $\int_n^{n+1}\sqrt{n}dx\le \int_n^{n+1}\sqrt{x}dx$ or $\sqrt{n}\le \int_n^{n+1}\sqrt{x}dx$.  Similarly for $x\le n$, we have $\int_{n-1}^n\sqrt{x}dx\le \int_{n-1}^n\sqrt{n}dx$ or $\int_{n-1}^n\sqrt{x}dx\le \sqrt{n}$

Comment: Ok i got it .One last thing , in the end when you wrote  Similary for  $x \leq n $ isnt it supposed to be $x \leq n+1$ according to the initial $n \leq x \leq n+1$

Comment: In my last comment I was more precise.  In each we are dealing with an interval of length one...  Where I said "finally" it is $n\le x \le n+1$, and "similarly" $n-1\le x \le n$.

Comment: Thank you a lot !!